# Strange nullpointer in supportmapfragment.getFragmentManager()

Tags: android, android-fragments, supportmapfragment, fragmentmanager

i have an application in which there's a list, and when you click on items in it, i display a detail view that contains, among other things, a map.

This has been out there for a while, but yesterday i got a strange crash log, first one ever since i deployed this version a couple of months back. It was on a Samsung Galaxy S4 running 4.4 according to the crash report.

Basically it says that

```
FragmentManager manager = mapFragment.getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
```

throws a nullpointerexception on the begintransaction call, apparently since the "getFragmentManager" on the line before returns null.

My mapfragment is initialized in the parent linearlayout (the one with the list) like so:

```
userStatusDetailsLayout = (UserStatusDetailsLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.userstatsdetails, container, false);
```

i then directly call

```
userStatusDetailsLayout.initCompononents(activity);
```

and in that method i initialize the mapfragment that caused the nullpointer:

```
mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) activity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.statsDetailMap);
```

I have never seen this on any of my test units, nor any of my testers. I am stumped. Is it something to with the timing of the inflate and findfragment? (the reason i'm inflating the detailslayout is that i don't want to do it unless someone actually wants to see it, and when they do i want to keep it and re-use it since it, especially on slower phones, is quite costly to inflate the map).

Posting this to see if anyone might have any idea when this would happen...

Comment: try this way  `SupportMapFragment fragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.statsDetailMap));` i overcome same issue in past and i solved by using this snip code.

Comment: Hey thanks for responding. But its not the fragment that is null. the fragmentmanager returned by fragment.getFragmentManager() is null. Once. Ever. :) As i mentioned, it always works for me and all others that are testing the app. Are you saying that that is the problem you also had? Trying to understand...

Comment: ok Now i got it. but then where you called `Fragmentmanager()`. How you add `Fragment` in transaction ?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) activity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.statsDetailMap);
```

to

```
mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.statsDetailMap);
```

Comment: But its not the fragment that is null. the fragmentmanager returned by fragment.getFragmentManager() is null. Once. Ever. :)